# NHibernate ICriteria search

Tags: nhibernate, hibernate

I have the following criteria search that I would expect to return 1 project with multiple task and contexts and a single user.

What is actually getting returned is the same project multiple times for each different task.

It almost looks like I am missing a statement in the criteria to tell the search to return unique projects.

Any help would be very welcome.

```
ICriteria criteria = NHibernateSession.Current.CreateCriteria(typeof(Project))
            .CreateAlias("User", "user")
            .Add(Restrictions.Eq("user.Username", username))
            .SetFetchMode("Tasks", FetchMode.Eager)
            .SetFetchMode("Contexts", FetchMode.Eager);

IList<Project> projects = criteria.List<Project>();
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure, but try adding `criteria.SetResultTransformer(new NHibernate.Transform.DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer());`

More info here: http://colinramsay.co.uk/diary/2008/01/15/nhibernate-optimising-queries-with-projections/

Answer (score 1):

IList<Project> projects = criteria.UniqueResult<Project>();

Comment: this will actually return only one result, what he wants is Distinct

Comment: UniqueResult doesnt return a list... https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/Criteria.html#uniqueResult()

Comment: Pedro I should have mentioned distinct in the post

Answer (score 1):

This is also a way to solve it:

[Eagerly loading entity associations efficiently with NHibernate](http://ayende.com/blog/4367/eagerly-loading-entity-associations-efficiently-with-nhibernate)